# Low download speed bug

Tags: bug, android-app

Whenever I use a 4G Internet connection and try to load a question or refresh my reputation or comments, when the dock bar on the right side of the screen appears, the download speed drops to almost zero and the application seems to not be doing anything at all.

Such behaviour is strange, because when I open Stack Exchange communities or view the head page the download speed is okay. Other applications run well too. With 3G or lower and Wi-Fi this problem doesn't occur.

What could be the cause of such strange behaviour of the mobile app?

P. S.: The website and questions load well and fast.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Xiaomi
- Device Model: Redmi Note 4

  - OS Version: 7.0 (V9.6.2.0.NCFMIFD)